# Firebase Data Swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I've got a little problem gaining objects from data base.It contains 4 objects(4 images specifically), they're coming but for some reason they overlap. If I print out query item, the logo shows 4 references to the images which is completely correct but when start setting data up to the image, instead of getting 4 images, I get 16. Is there any way to fix? I though it could be fixed by changing the model from struct to class to avoid duplicating but it didn't work out. Maybe a triple loop causes the problem.

```
class APIManager {
    
    private init() {}
    static let shared = APIManager()
    
    func fetchData(collectionType: CollectionType, completion: @escaping (Document) -> Void) {
        let dataBase = self.configureFireBase()
        dataBase.collection(collectionType.rawValue).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error received trying to get data: \(error)")
            }else{
                guard let query = querySnapshot?.documents else {return}
                for queryItem in query {
                    for(name, price) in queryItem.data() {
                        if name == "field1" {
                            self.getImage { (sneakerImage) in
                                let documentToAppend = Document(name: queryItem.documentID, field1: price as? String ?? "", field2: queryItem.documentID, image: sneakerImage)
                                completion(documentToAppend)
                                   
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private func getImage(imageHandler: @escaping (UIImage)->Void) {
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let reference = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://sneakershop-b309a.appspot.com").child("pictures")
        reference.listAll { (result, error) in
            for item in result.items {
                print(item)
                item.getData(maxSize: 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }else{
                        guard let image = UIImage(data: data ?? Data()) else {return}
                        imageHandler(image)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private func configureFireBase() -> Firestore {
        var db: Firestore!
        let settings = FirestoreSettings()
        Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        return db
    }
}
```

Comment: Firebase has several different services.  Which are you referring to?

Comment: @ElTomato I'm referring to fire storage where I keep images

Comment: name?  price?  Where do they come from?  We don't even know what kind of data you have with Firebase Storage.  Nobody can proof your code unless you provide more information.